# MySQL Add month and modify day in update query

Tags: mysql, date, sql-update

I need to modify several dates in a table using a mysql **update** statement.

Here is the problem: I need to modify each date adding 1 month and setting the day to 7.

Rule: **+1 month and day needs to be 7**

- 2015-10-10 => 2015-11-07
- 2015-11-05 => 2015-12-07
- 2015-12-21 => 2016-01-07
- ....

It's pretty easy do add a month, i've already tried using `DATE_ADD(eventdate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)` but i need to **change** the day as well.

Started building the following query:

`UPDATE receipts SET due_date = DATE_ADD(due_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) WHERE ...`

Now i need to change the **day**.

How to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this (don't forget to add your `WHERE` clause):

```
UPDATE receipts 
SET due_date = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(due_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-'), '07')
```